# For Loop while referring to an array with Length

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm very new to javascript and have just recently learned about For loops. I have a variable that consists of an array containing a bunch names, and I would like to add last names to each of them. I wrote the code as shown below and have a few questions.

```js
let name = ["john", "maria", "brandon", "gaby", "jessica", "angel"];

function addLastName(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(name[i] + " (please insert last name)")
  }
}

console.log(addLastName(name))
```

Result :

```
john (please insert last name)
maria (please insert last name)
brandon (please insert last name)
gaby (please insert last name)
jessica (please insert last name)
angel (please insert last name)
undefined
```

Questions:

1. About the second statement for the loop. Correct me if I'm wrong, but when using length in an array, it will show the amount of data inside the array right? So in this case, `name.length = 6`. But to my understanding, when accessing a part of an array, the count always starts at 0. So I used array.length-1. But the result didn't show "Angel". When I used `array.length`, the result showed Angel. What logic am I missing here?
2. When I put the result on the console, there's always an "undefined" at the end of it, whether I used `array.length` or `array.length-1`. Can anybody tell me why it showed up?

Comment: You are not returning (ie: using `return` inside of `addLastName`), that's why when you log the result of calling `addLastName()` you see `undefined`.

Comment: For 1. `i<array.length` so `i` is always less than the length of the array. That way it is correct.  The other way would be to write `for (let i=0;i<= array.length-1 ;i++)` it takes four more characters and is not used by the community.

Comment: for this "But the result didn't show "Angel". When i used array.length, the result showed Angel." when you want to use `array.length -1` then you need to use condition `<=`. As per current code it's correct because you are already checking `i < array.length` for 2nd question you already using console inside of function so no need from outside. it is printing undefined because you are not returning anything from `addLastName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

Inside the for loop, if you start from 0, and the condition is `i < array.length` and the length of the array is 6, it will go from 0 to 5, and when it reaches 6 it will not respect the condition (6 < 6 `false`) so it will exit the `for` loop before executing the block inside (but when you exited the for, `i` will be 6).

For your second question:

You should not call `console.log(addLastName(name))` because `addLastName` already logs to the `console`. That `console.log` is the one that prints `undefined` since it will print the result of the function, which is `undefined` by default if you do not return anything inside the function.

Comment: oh my god i just realized my mistakes. 
1. For some reason i didn't realize that `i<array.length` is actually the correct one because it stops at 5 (which is "angel"), and when i used `array.length-1`  it stops at 4, this not showing "angel". 

2. Again my mistake, i forgot that i've used console.log inside the loop. 

thank you so much for willing to reply to my stupid questions!